# Where condition is null, how to make all selection

Tags: mysql

I am stuck on mysql issue. Where my example is as follow

```
select * from table where id <= (select id from another_table)
```

works well if another_table return some number but what if the value is null. i want to select all record if another_table in case of null value

i.e.

```
(select id from another_table) is null
```

it should become or behave like

```
select * from table where
```

Comment: Are the tables related (some relation between them, etc)? Give some more info, what you want, did you join them?

Comment: @Rolice actually both table is same i.e. table name is same

Comment: You mean you are doing something like self join (the same table) not two with the same structure?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function?

```
select * from table where id <= coalesce((select id from another_table), N);
```

where 'N' is the maximum value that can be stored in the "id" column, e.g. `2147483647` for `INT`.

Comment: select * from points 
where id < coalesce((select null as id), max(id)) dont work

Answer (score 0):

storing result of subquery in variable will do the trick for you:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table a, (SELECT @id:= (SELECT id FROM another_table LIMIT 1)) c
WHERE @id IS NULL OR id <= @id;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select @id := (select max(id) from table);
select * from another_table where id 
         <(case when @id is null then id else @id end)
```